# usb 3-5:string descriptor 0 read error: -22

Tags: linux, usb, bluetooth, archlinux

При загрузке системы и выходе из сна получаю следующую ошибку в журналах (а при выходе из сна и в консоли непосредственно):

> **usb 3-5:string descriptor 0 read error: -22**

Нагуглил много подобных проблем, но нигде нет объяснения, с чем это связано. При отключении `bluetooth` в `UEFI setup` ошибка исчезает, но мне он нужен. Все `usb` порты работают нормально (по крайней мере флешка монтируется везде), `bluetooth` с помощью `bluetoothctl` находит девайсы, но соединение не устанавливается (не знаю, связано ли это с вопросом).

Вот `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 13d3:3474 IMC Networks Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`upd`: после выхода из сна получил новый `lsusb`, теперь уже ясно, что проблема с `bluetooth`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 13d3:3474 IMC Networks Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`upd2`: вообще, номер девайса меняется после каждого выхода из сна, вот что происходит в `dmesg` (теперь номер 7):

```
[ 1775.013491] usb 3-5: string descriptor 0 read error: -22
[ 1775.052019] usb 3-5: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 1775.332396] usb 3-5: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 1775.463764] usb 3-5: string descriptor 0 read error: -22
```